# Google Places Api iOS Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded error

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

I am trying to use google places api for iOS. I created an api key and then I am trying to call a few methods. I have entered the api key in the app but when I make the call I get an this error

> ```
> lookup place id query error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.places.server.ErrorDomain error -1.)
> Error Domain=com.google.places.server.ErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8bf861ca80 {Error
> ```
>
> Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=403 "(Daily Limit for
>   Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.)"
>   UserInfo={error=Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded.
>   Continued use requires signup., NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Daily Limit
>   for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.),
>   GTLStructuredError=GMSx_GTLErrorObject 0x7f8bf2be6060: {message:"Daily
>   Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires
>   signup." data:[1] code:403}}}}

I provide the api key in my appdelegate using GMSServices.provideAPIKey("MY_API_KEY") and I 've given location access to the app. I certainly haven't exceed my usage limits (my quota shows 0 out of 1000) since I haven't been able to talk with the api. I 've regenerated the key some times and I also have created other keys with other gmail accounts but nothing worked...

My guess is either something is not right with the ios simulator location (I ve provided a gpx file to pass a custom location) or something is wrong from google's side.

The two samples that I have in my code are:

```
                let placeID = "ChIJV4k8_9UodTERU5KXbkYpSYs"

            placesClient.lookUpPlaceID(placeID, callback: { (place: GMSPlace?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if let error = error {
                    print("lookup place id query error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    print(error)
                    return
                }

                if let place = place {
                    print("Place name \(place.name)")
                    print("Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
                    print("Place placeID \(place.placeID)")
                    print("Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
                } else {
                    print("No place details for \(placeID)")
                }
            })
```

and

```
                placesClient.currentPlaceWithCallback({ (placeLikelihoods, error) -> Void in
                guard error == nil else {
                    print("Current Place error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }

                if let placeLikelihoods = placeLikelihoods {
                    for likelihood in placeLikelihoods.likelihoods {
                        let place = likelihood.place
                        print("Current Place name \(place.name) at likelihood \(likelihood.likelihood)")
                        print("Current Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
                        print("Current Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
                        print("Current PlaceID \(place.placeID)")
                    }
                }
            })
```

placesClient is a var instantiated as GMSPlacesClient().
Am I missing something here? 
The rest of the code is a typical Xcode single application project.

Comment: It says "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded". That would indicate that you are actually not logged in. That means that the daily limit per IP address applies, not your quota.

Comment: Could you give more details please? Where do I have to log in? I created my app and got my api key. Then I use that key in my code to connect with the api. In which point should I log in?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Answering my own question here!

Turns out the mistake was totally mine (as it usually is). I was setting the placesClient var like this

```
var placesClient = GMSPlacesClient()
```

In google's example ([check it here](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start)) the placesClient var is declared as an optional GMSPlacesClient and then in viewDidLoad is set to GMSPlacesClient.sharedClient(). Unfortunately I missed that part. The code is like

```
var placesClient: GMSPlacesClient?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.sharedClient()
}
```