# Occured error after updating GooglePlaces framework (Ver 2.0.1)

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, google-places-api

I updated GooglePlaces framework for my iPhone app.
Framework version is 2.0.1.

***(1.13.2 -> 2.0.1)***

I updated GoogleMaps and GooglePlaces.

### **placesClient.autocompleteQuery(searchText!, bounds: nil, filter: nil)....**

This method was occured error that Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded.

***But method call count was under daily limit.***

Method error message  refer to below.

---

```
Error Domain=com.google.places.ErrorDomain Code=-3 
"An internal error occurred in the Places API library. If you believe this error represents a bug, please file a report using the instructions on our community and support page (https://developers.google.com/places/support)." 

UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An internal error occurred in the Places API library. If you believe this error represents a bug, please file a report using the instructions on our community and support page (https://developers.google.com/places/support).,

NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8e00332950 {Error Domain=com.google.places.server.ErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)" 

UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8e0012ca30 {Error Domain=com.google.GTLRErrorObjectDomain Code=403 "(Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.)" 

UserInfo={error=Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup., GTLRStructuredError=GMSx_GTLRErrorObject 0x7f8dfae31a80: {message:"Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup." errors:[1] code:403}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.)
```

---

I updated just framework version.
What was wrong?

Please advise how to resolve.

Comment: Check it out this link. I think it will solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397676/google-places-api-ios-daily-limit-for-unauthenticated-use-exceeded-error

Comment: @Fsousa Thanks. I solved my app problem.